# Ubuntu Software center Download seems to have stopped

Tags: 12.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and I was trying to download Skype when it just stopped with the bar roughly around 25% and when I go to progress it says "Skype" then "Applying Changes" below it, and the bar all the way at the end about 25% orange.

Comment: How long progress bar remained at 25%? Please add that to the question. For many applications, it is quite normal for the progress bar to stay at a place for say 2-5 minutes and then you may notice it suddenly reached 100%

Answer (score 0):

Install Skype Using terminal. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

give password.. Packages for Skype will be downloaded and installed automatically.

After completing Process , You can find Skype installed